# mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); not working in fragment map

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions, location

I have done all required permissions from menifest and runtime but it is not working in my devices for current location in google map

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
View view;
ImageView locAddress;
AppLocationService appLocationService;
AutoCompleteTextView edtStartPoint;
EditText togo;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
private static final String API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";
private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 11;
private GoogleMap mMap;

ImageView imgLoc;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);

    if (mapFragment != null) {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    locAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.locAddress);
    edtStartPoint = view.findViewById(R.id.edtStartPoint);
    imgLoc = view.findViewById(R.id.imgLoc);
    edtStartPoint.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_text));
    edtStartPoint.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            getActivity());
    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getActivity())) {

    } else {
        showSnack(true);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    mMap = map;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        setMyLocationEnabled();
    }
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    map.setOnMapClickListener(latLng -> {
        BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
        bottomSheetFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
    });


}

public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:gr");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        Log.e("@@sb", sb.toString());

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("@@", "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("@@", "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");


        resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            System.out.println("====");
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("@@", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return String.valueOf(resultList.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}


private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(coordinatorLayout, "No Internet", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("OK", view -> {
                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "ok", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar1.show();
            });
    snackbar.show();
}

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setMyLocationEnabled();
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}

private void setMyLocationEnabled() {
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            //TODO:
        }
    });
}
}
```

Please suggest me thank you in advance I would appreciate every answer

Comment: Please refer : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3365

Comment: I think you do not need to add this  mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); it is by default enabled

Comment: and check also whether you have given the location permission to your application.

Comment: It throws the exception? Or simply not navigate to current location?

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey